# DRY way to replace button text with icon without changing button size

Tags: html, css

Throughout my web app I have various submit buttons.  I am able to disable them after a user submits to prevent multiple post requests and submissions to the server.  I also replace the text of the button with a font awesome spinner icon.  "Approve" becomes `<i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>`.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="approve-button" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/approve?id=40">
  Approve
</a>

#approve-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 138px;
}
```

Since the text and font-size is dictating the size of the buttons, when I replace the text with the icon, the button shrinks.  The only way I see the prevent this is to manually set the button height and width.  But I have to do this for all buttons.

Is there a simpler way where I don't have to manually set the height and width of all buttons?

Comment: `min-width:138px` ? Or simply find the widest button, and set them all to that? You could also use jQuery to set a fixed width on click, before changing to image - means it keeps size even when you put the text back.

Comment: `fa` icons are text too. So maybe you set text size for it somewhere?

Comment: set it with a classname instead of ID's ?

Comment: when you replace the text - set the width and height for that element too

Comment: @SlackBadger All my buttons are different sizes, I don't want the size to change when the text gets replaced with an icon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the `min-width` & `min-height` or by grabbing the existing width and height, and applying an inline-style at the same time you swap the spinner.

**OR**

If you want to be strictly CSS based, you can set two span elements within the button: one for the spinner, and the button label. Thus, position `absolute` the span spinner to sit above the button, and when your spinner is `active` (`display: block`), and make the span label hidden (`visibility: hidden`) -- this will keep the proportion of the button.

To demonstrate: forked off of TheEarlyMan's answer: http://codepen.io/brh55/pen/yJNbmP

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but [here's a solution codepen link](http://codepen.io/vividuaelsaphe/pen/qNdraq)

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="approve-button" rel="nofollow" >
  <span>Approve</span>
  <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>
</a>
```

**Jquery**
$(".fa").hide();

```
$("#approve-button").click(function() {
  $("span").hide();
  $(".fa").show();
});
```